# Forcing Chrome for Windows to respect sub-pixel line heights

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm having a tricky CSS issue. This is exacerbated by the fact that the CSS for the "theme" of the web site is third-party (it can't be changed, but we can override with another stylesheet), and everything on the page uses absolute positioning for layout and sizing (this cannot be changed).

Somewhere in this third-party CSS, we have this declaration:

```
body {
    line-height: 1.3;
}
```

A `div` on the page has a `font-size` of `14px`, making its line height `18.2px`. This is fine for typical web sites. However, since everything is positioned absolutely using pixel positions, font rendering differences are coming into play. Specifically, Google Chrome in Windows is rounding this `line-height` down to `18px`. This means that the large block of content in the `div` renders substantially shorter in Chrome for Windows than in any other browser. All other browsers seem to support sub-pixel line heights.

Is there any way to force Chrome for Windows to respect sub-pixel line heights so that it doesn't render so differently than other browsers?

**Update**

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J2kEW/1/) demonstrating the difference. If you compare the heights in Chrome for Windows and, say, Firefox for Windows, you'll see that there's a `0.2px` difference per line.

Comment: Are you really sure about other browsers _not_ rounding 18.2 down to 18?

Comment: I checked dev tools on both Chrome and Firefox. Firefox display 18.2px, but I guess on rasterizing the font, everything will aligned on whole pixels.

Comment: They definitely render differently. The `0.2px` per line adds up over multiple lines.

Comment: I have tried this and there was no visual difference. There would've been 1 additional pixel after the 5th line (2 after 10 lines and so on). You should make a demo with http://jsfiddle.net, which we can check in different browsers.

Comment: See my update, @kleinfreund. You may not see the difference, because `0.2px` is small, but this is making a noticeable difference in my case because there are many lines.

Comment: This is right. In chrome you have a height of 514px and in Firefox it's 519.4 px. You may want to override the font-sizes and line-heights then. :x

Comment: Don't use pixels if possible.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is changing the `line-height` to something that multiplies up to a whole pixel. In your case:

```
line-height: 1.2857142857142857142857142857143; /* = 18 / 14 */
```

This changes the output only a little, and results in cross-browser compatible result.

I've tested it with your fiddle on Chrome and Firefox on Windows and it works.